# PHP Preg_match always return true

Tags: php, wordpress, preg-replace, preg-match

im trying to retreive a list of Wordpress Posts with get_posts,

After that, i want to search in the post_content if there any match of a specific string.

right now, my code is:

```
if(preg_match('/\b[download id="2"]\b/i', $value->post_content)){
       echo('match');
}else{
       echo('nomatch');
}
```

But it return alway a match.

What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Could you give an example of what you want to match and what you don't want to match. Cuz i can't figure it out with your description

Comment: Escape the square brackets: `/\b\[download id="2"\]\b/i`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Square brackets means to match against any of the characters specified, so in your case it's matching `d` or `o` or `w` or `n` or `l` or `a` or  or `i` or `=` or `"` or `2`.

If you want to match `download id="2"` in a string then you need to use `/(download id="2")/i`. If you want to match `[download id="2"]` then you need to escape the square brackets like this: `/(\[download id="2"\])/i`